# Inicializadores en Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, funciones

Alguien me podría explicar de forma simple y clara la diferencia entre inicializadores designados y los inicializadores de conveniencia? Si es posible con algún ejemplo básico para entenderlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una clase tiene un inicializador designado, sin embargo, puede tener varios inicializadores de conveniencia. Los inicializadores de conveniencia son ayudantes, tienen que invocar al inicializador designado de la misma clase, sí o sí (e.g. `self.init(name: name, age: 8)`), para inicializar la clase. Se usan los inicializadores de conveniencia porque son *convenientes*, normalmente llevan menos parámetros, dando un valor por defecto a los demás parámetros.

1. **Ejemplo 1**: Una clase

   ```
   class Animal {
       var name: String
       var age: Int

       // designated initializer
       init(name: String, age: Int) {
           self.name = name
           self.age = age
       }

       /// convenience initializer, gives a default age value
       convenience init(name: String) {
           self.init(name: name, age: 8)
       }
   }
   let dog = Animal(name: "Beethoven")
   print(dog.name)
   ```
2. **Ejemplo 2**: Un `UIView` subclass (sin storyboard/xib)

   `UIView` es un caso especial porque tiene dos inicializadores, `init(frame:)` (cuando el view se inicializa programaticamente) *y también* `init(coder:)` (cuando el view se inicializa desde un storyboard o nib, que podemos ignorar porque solo Xcode llama a este método cuando crea el view a partir del storyboard/xib).

   ```
   class AnimalView: UIView {
       var name: String
       var age: Int

       // designated initializer
       init(name: String, age: Int) {
           self.name = name
           self.age = age
           super.init(frame: CGRectZero)  // invocamos al designated initializer del superclass
       }

       /// convenience initializer, gives a default age value
       convenience init(name: String) {
           self.init(name: name, age: 8)
       }

       // No vamos a llamar a este método
       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
   }
   let dog = AnimalView(name: "Beethoven")
   print(dog.name)
   ```